# Why does Ubuntu change the time when installing?

Tags: system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 onto a brand new hard drive with no other drives attached. After the install my system time was 2:45 PM instead of 7:45 AM.
Why the change?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu assumes that your hardware time (bios time) is in UTC time. When you provide the timezone (whilst installation) it will shift system time according to your timezone.

You probably have local time (GMT+5 I guess) set in BIOS.

This is a common problem when you have multiboot configuration with one system assuming BIOS is in UTC time (Linux) and another assumes BIOS is in local time (Windows).

Comment: If you have dual boot Windows - Ubuntu you can change the behaviour of Ubuntu to match that of Windows:
edit /etc/default/rcS
add or change the following section:
# Set UTC=yes if your hardware clock is set to UTC (GMT)
UTC=no

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will choose language, time settings, etc from the country you selected when you installed. If you said you're from Brazil but now live in Russia, for instance, then the time will be wrong. You can change the time zone by right-clicking the clock on your panel and selecting Time settings.